# ipad: jquery animation lags through onscreenkeyboard

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-animate

I'm writing a webapp for mobile devices.

The app includes some fancy pagination pageflip effect i've written using jquery.animate(), which works quite nice and fast in general.

My problem on ipad: after the user clicked into a textarea / input text field, the onscreenkeyboard appears and the pageflip effect lags as hell.

When i click somewhere else afterwards - and the onscreenkeyboard dissappears - the animation still lags the same way, huh.

Anybody knows how to avoid that lag?

Comment: The reason was: i used css shadows (-webkit-shadow-box, etc). They were too large (10px) for the ipad to render fast enough togehter with the anim. I made them smaller and the anim works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing something custom for the iPad, I would recommend that you use CSS3 animations directly. Memory management in javascript apps for the iPad is a sonofabitch.